# iOS Paypal Completed Payment Details

Tags: ios, sdk, paypal

Hi I'm working on an iOS app which I'm trying to integrate PayPals SDK in. I downloaded and followed the guide on their github page here https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK I set up everything and set my client_id and the sandbox email address they gave me and I have the environment set as `PayPalEnvironmentSandbox`. Once everything goes through I'm given the following in the `payPalPaymentDidComplete` method, however, I need a lot more information than this about the user. For instance their address so I know where to ship to, their name, their email etc. How can I get this information after the transaction is completed?

```
CurrencyCode: USD
Amount: 4.27
Short Description: Prison Cards
Processable: No
Display: $4.27
Confirmation: {
    client =     {
        environment = mock;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "1.3.5";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    payment =     {
        amount = "4.27";
        "currency_code" = USD;
        "short_description" = "Prison Cards";
    };
    "proof_of_payment" =     {
        "adaptive_payment" =         {
            "app_id" = "APP-1234567890";
            "pay_key" = "AP-70M68096ML426802W";
            "payment_exec_status" = COMPLETED;
            timestamp = "2013-11-04T16:14:55Z";
        };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the transaction has completed you should pass proof of payment to your server for verification as described here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

In addition PaymentDetails call will get sender email address. Unfortunately shipping address is not yet supported.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is the point then of using PayPal SDK on iOS if you can't get their shipping address? Since Apple TOS say you can only use outside merchants for physical goods otherwise you have to use their IAP. So before they make their purchase I have to collect their shipping info I assume? Shouldn't this be quick and easy for my user? What user is gonna want to fill out a whole form.

Comment: Thank you for the answer though sorry I'm a bit annoyed with PayPal now if that's the case ha